# What are bad use cases for Jackson/JSON?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

What would be characteristics or smells that would indicate it is a **bad** idea to use Jackson/JSON for a particular task or set of tasks?  I'm still learning about this technology, and I don't want to fall into the trap of treating everything like a nail just because I happen to have a fancy new hammer to play with.

For example, if my objects tend to have a lot of fields that are not basic types (by basic types I mean things like String or Double), is that an indication that Jackson/JSON would be inappropriate for serializing and deserializing?  I don't want to overly dwell on this example, but that should give a feel of the type of thing I am wondering about.

Comment: Do you mean Java specific only? Including web?

Comment: Well I'm working with Java, **not** including web, so that's why I tagged as Java and that's what I personally am interested in.

Comment: I do not understand why this was closed; characteristics of when a technology/paradigm/technique are inappropriate can certainly involve facts and references and need not solicit opinion.  There can be objective answers as to things that cannot be done in this way or that involve jumping through a ridiculous number of hoops to do.  Given that `code-smells` is not only on-topic but has its own tag, it seems like questions of this form should be on-topic as well.

Comment: Assuming too wide a question and may end in debate, with no single answer, since most smells come down to architecture being abused. Surprised it was closed rather than made community wiki though.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to transfer data, you need to pick a format.  Json is as good as any other; its flexible and simple.  Xml is also a possibility, as is a custom format (although i would not use a custom format when there are some many good standards).

Json is a good choice.  There are a plethora of json parsers/writers in all common languages, and even most esoteric languages.  Having complex types is not a problem, as you can always do something like

```
{
  "complexValue": {
    "part1": "foo",
    "part2": "bar"
    ...
  }
}
```

EDIT - from comments: Sometimes the best tool is the one you know. If you are not transferring data, object serialization is ok. Its ok for transmitting data too, unless you want to talk to non-java services

Comment: This sounds like you are saying that I shouldn't worry about my hammer because the entire universe is full of nails?

Comment: Im saying that json is a good nail.  Also, what are your options?  Json is very general -- its just a standard/format for transmitting data.

Comment: @Michael - More like you pick whatever hammer you're comfortable with, because most of them are completely capable of... well, hammering nails. If you like the format, use it when it's supported. If not, use another supported format.

Comment: @hvgotcodes Well before I got involved with it we were using XML at one point and then switched to JSON.  Without getting into details, I now have a more complicated use case and am worried about forcing a square peg into a round hole.  I know everyone hates standard Java serialization but I'm wondering whether that is more appropriate for me (but this is starting to deviate a little from the original question as written).  My use case is actually not for transferring data per se but for storing and recreating aspects of a desktop application.

Comment: @michael, use whatever is simplest for you.  Sometimes the best tool is the one you know. If you are not transferring data, object serialization is ok.  Its ok for transmitting data too, unless you want to talk to non-java services

Answer (score 0):

I know you've asked for Java, but a common smell for the web:

- Using JSON to send objects to the client and building HTML in JavaScript when you already have server code/view to build HTML.

This gives you two sets of code of maintain.

Comment: This entirely depends on what kind of application you are building.

Comment: @Jeremy +1 It does, but it's still a code smell.

Comment: that depends right.. you might hv content thats only rendered on the client side.. and you must hv heard of templating engines that gives you both server and client side engines like Mustache..

Comment: I have worked on an app that doesnt send markup from the server at all since you might end up transferring lots of redundant markup.. instead just build the same on the client side and send the required json

Comment: @zzzz that's why I have qualified it with `"when you already have server code/view to build HTML."`

Comment: does that mean you shouldnt use both?

Comment: For the most part yes, else you violate DRY and have to maintain two sets of code and can create subtle bugs with changes that don't sync the HTML building code.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat broad question, and it might make sense to split into two parts (using JSON as a format, Jackson as a lib). But either way I do not think that complex objects are problematic: Jackson is designed to handle complicated object structures and types (including generic types) just fine. Benefits of data binding (convenience, very little code to write) are also more noticeable with more complex objects.
Jackson also supports other JSON manipulation methods (streaming, tree-based), but I assume your question is most related to automatic data-binding.

Common challenge with using automatic data-binding is that it can add close coupling between external data format (in JSON) and your object model. Meaning that change in one often requires coordinated change in the other. Adding layers between the two (such as manually handling data binding) can help but is more work.
This is not unique to JSON (XML data binding with libs like JAXB has similar challenges), or even data formats: Hibernate and other ORM libs can also add more close-coupling.
Another potential challenge is that of losing visibility into what is happening: data binding is often a black box, and when things work, that's great (fewer things to worry about), but when they don't trouble-shooting may be more difficult.